# Cast reflection "Type" to a List<class> in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In my Kotlin code, I have a variable that is the Type interface from
java.lang.reflect

```
var type: Type
```

But I need to cast this to:

```
List<UserInfo>
```

If I was not casting to a List, I would just do this:

```
var type = UserInfo::class.java
```

and this works. But I don't know how to cast it using a List. The closest I found is this:

```
var type = Array<UserInfo>::class.java
```

This would compile if my UserInfo was an Array but it's a List.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you please give a better example and what you're trying to do?

Comment: var type = List<UserInfo>::class.java
But this will not compile.

Comment: https://google.com/?q=type+erasure

Comment: Do you use any other libraries available which need this type? Gson maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The issue (as @Miha_x64 says) is [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) [erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

The Java Virtual Machine knows nothing about type parameters.  So although the source specified a `List<UserInfo>`, it compiles down to a plain `List`.

So this works:

```
var type = List::class.java
```

(Your `Array` example works because arrays are a special case: they're directly supported in the JVM, and keep their types at runtime.)

Java's use of type erasure is at least partly for historical reasons; when generics were added to Java 5, they wanted to preserve compatibility with existing source and bytecode.  For all the gory details (much of which is inherited by Kotlin), see [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its late. Try to use [KTypeProjection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type-projection/) and [createType()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-type.html) with KClass instead. Then get the value in KType or convert it back to java Type.

```
val kClass = YourClass::class
val kTypeProjection = KTypeProjection.invariant(entity.starProjectedType)
val kType = List::class.createType(listOf(kTypeProjection))
val type = kType.javaType
```

result:

```
kType: kotlin.collections.List<YourClass>
type: java.util.List<YourClass>
```